# How to get around organization blocking SSH in a way I don't understand?

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I am by no means a networking expert, so I am rather confused as to how my organization is blocking SSH. At first I assumed that they were blocking traffic on port 22, so I tried several other ports to no avail. My next conclusion was that they closed all nonstandard ports, but using an online tool I was able to determine this is not the case. When I try to connect, all seems to go well at first but I get an error and a connection closed after 30 seconds or so.

For the record, I am using PUTTY on Windows to connect to an Ubuntu server. And, yes, I have tried connecting to a computer that was not my original destination.

Essentially, does anyone have a theory as to what they are doing and/or how I can circumvent it?

Comment: One wonders why they blocked it - security??

Comment: You would need to provide an error message for us to hazard a guess.  My guess is they are using public/private key infrastructure and you don't have a valid public key, so your connection is failing.    It could also be a honeypot or a miriad of other things.   But hey, if you want us to help you get fired for hacking, post away...

Comment: I voted to close the question as off-topic because it's about "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks". The right thing to do is to work along with the IT department of your organization, not against it. Contact them and ask for clarification and assistance.

Comment: I disagree that "how is SSH being blocked" is an issue specific to a corporate IT network.  In fact, with a little more information this question could be answerable on SU. However, as written it lacks sufficient detail to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is

1. Get off the company network and onto a private Wifi network.  Either a phone tether or a specially setup local WiFi network

Other possibilities are

2. Establish a VPN to somewhere else then SSH  - This is a dubious practice- Even for my role where I provide network support to other companies over VPNs and they pay my company to provide support. Connecting to someone else's VPN from inside my companies network is a security hole.  So don't do this.
3. Setup some proxy/redirect ie connect as SSH but on a different port , this sounds like what you tried - However an Intrusion Prevention system should recognize the traffic as not valid and kill it. However if it is expected to be encrypted traffic eg https then the IPS may have a harder time realizing its SSH and so leave it alone.  By doing this you are deliberately hiding what you are doing and so I would expect "counseling" if found